# Could I write a review paper as my B.Tech (Bachelors in Technology) final year project, rather than presenting an experiment based work?

Tags: engineering, bachelor, india, chemistry, project-design

I live in India.
Currently due to the coronavirus pandemic, all colleges have been shut down and the country has gone in lockdown. As a result, my final year project work on electrocoagulation has come to a standstill.
The apparatus and the materials took time to arrive, and when they finally did and I was beginning to do the experimental work, the colleges were shutdown. 
In the light of these events, my mentor has suggested me to write a review paper instead, however I am afraid it might not be accepted as a final year project.
Therefore, for my own peace of mind, I would like to know if a review paper could work as a final year B.Tech project.

Comment: That is up to your university entirely. Your mentor should be the one to answer the question. Or an official at the university. The advice from here is worthless.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the official site of your university and see if you get the solution for your question otherwise you can ask your mentor or guide for research and they will help you for sure. 
It is probably possible that they will allow you to write a review paper, rather than doing a final year project because the system is totally based on credits and credits are nothing but the amount of hours you put in to get a credit and writing a review paper is a difficult job and needs lots of hours to do , so I think they will allow you to that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to ask your university - they are the ones issuing you a degree, they're also the ones who know what you need to achieve before issuing you a degree.

That said, there's a good chance the answer will be "no", because these final year projects are intended to give students a taste of research. Writing a review isn't a taste of research. It's the first step, but one still needs to do something more before getting to the end product.

Comment: Actually, the answer may well be "yes" as universities need to find a way to be fair to students who's research has been disrupted. It is pretty hard to do chemistry research without access to a lab.

Comment: There is a good chance the answer will be yes, especially as the mentor suggested it!!